# Installing Ubuntu problem "the partition assigned to starts at an offset"

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 13.04

When I wanted to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop(HP ENVY 17) i got this problem.

[image]

Output from  sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda :

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 58F18688-CA8F-4E96-AC22-95B762F30F18
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          821247   400.0 MiB   2700  Basic data partition
   2          821248         1353727   260.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
   3         1353728         1615871   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved part
   4         1615872      1895444479   903.0 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   5      1895444480      1953523711   27.7 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
```

Comment: You are mixing up your sda and sdb.  According to the picture, sda5 is an ntfs windows recovery partition and it is sdb5 that the installer is complaining about.  How did you create that partition, and you need to have gdisk list sdb, not sda.

Comment: Did you ever solve?

Answer (score 4):

Just switch from ext to xfs format, fixed the problem from me

Comment: Thank you Roshan for your simple quick solution. It worked for Ubuntu 18.04 on USB SSD.

Comment: Thanks for saving time to find the solns.

Answer (score 3):

First, I recommend you read [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/) for background on the problem.

Second, you need to use a partitioning tool that enables you to view and specify partition start points to the sector, rather than rounded (2MiB or 12.7GiB or whatnot). I'm not sure if the Ubuntu installer can do this, offhand. You may need to quit from the installer and use a tool like [`gdisk`,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) which comes with Linux emergency CDs like [System Rescue CD.](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) Alternatively, most tools align partitions properly by default. I thought that the Ubuntu installer did this, but either it's got a bug or you prepared your partitions using some other tool. If the latter, you could simply delete the partition and re-create it with the Ubuntu installer to fix the problem.

If you need more help, I recommend you boot an emergency disc and show us the output of one of the following two commands:

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print
```